# Cygwin to execute windows shortcut files (.LNK)

Tags: windows, windows-8, cygwin, shortcuts

I use Cygwin as my cmd replacement on Windows and I am in the process of cleaning up my system PATH variable.

I now have a folder containing exe's and shortcuts (.LNK) files which is in PATH containing all the small apps and software I use from the command line.

Everything works through CMD, however the shortcuts, .LNK files, do not work through Cygwin. 
Instead I get

> bash: /cygdrive/e/Apps/uniserver.lnk: cannot execute binary file

My only guess is because it thinks .lnk is supposed to be a symlink?

Is there anyway to get Cygwin to launch the shortcut?

Comment: If you need to know where a shortcut points (a slightly different issue), you can use `readshortcut foo.lnk`.  (Leaving a comment here so I'll be able to find the information again myself in the future :) .)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can execute Windows LNK files from Cygwin using the `cygstart` utility, part of [cygutils package](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=cygutils&arch=x86), as follows:

```
cygstart [OPTION]... FILE [ARGUMENTS]
```

See [`cygstart --help`](https://gist.github.com/famousgarkin/0c04fa1fd423a5ccd370) for the options available.

The following should be enough in your case:

```
cygstart /cygdrive/e/Apps/uniserver.lnk
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar setup and thought if I could save typing `.lnk` each time. Tried  [`command_not_found_handle` hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html) added as of Bash 4.0 and it looks like working:

```bash
# add this to your .bashrc
command_not_found_handle ()
{
    if [[ $1 == *.* || $1 == */* ]]; then
        echo "$1: command not found"
        return 127
    fi

    local binbase=/cygdrive/e/Apps/
    local name=$1
    shift

    # You might want to tweak precedence
    if [[ -f ./$name.bat ]]; then
        exec "./$name.bat" "$@"
    elif [[ -f ./$name.lnk ]]; then
        cygstart "./$name.lnk" "$@"
    elif [[ -f $binbase/$name.bat ]]; then
        exec "$binbase/$name.bat" "$@"
    elif [[ -f $binbase/$name.lnk ]]; then
        cygstart "$binbase/$name.lnk" "$@"
    else
        echo "$name: command not found"
        return 127
    fi
}
```

e.g. Typing just `uniserver` fires this hook and finds `/cygdrive/e/Apps/uniserver.lnk` to launch.

**Edit:** An alternative which finds shortcuts from entire $PATH.

```bash
command_not_found_handle ()
{
    if [[ $1 == *.* || $1 == */* ]]
    then
        echo "$1: command not found"
        return 127
    fi

    local name=$1
    shift

    if [[ -f ./$name.bat ]]
    then
        exec "./$name.bat" "$@"
    elif [[ -f ./$name.lnk ]]
    then
        start "./$name.lnk" "$@"
    elif [[ -f $(type -P $name.bat) ]]
    then
        exec "$(type -P $name.bat)" "$@"
    elif [[ -f $(type -P $name.lnk) ]]
    then
        cygstart "$(type -P $name.lnk)" "$@"
    else
        echo "$name: command not found"
        return 127
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOS built-in command `start`.  I'm guessing Cygwin does NOT have access to DOS built-ins, though, so you'll have to write a wrapper, like mystart.bat, and launch your LNK's my using the wrapper script.

I don't think you can "associate" the LNK files in Cygwin to make Cygwin automatically launch your wrapper, but perhaps someone else can suggest a way to do that.